# Python reuse regular expression

Tags: python, expression

I have to match a text.

Ej:

```
text = 'C:x=-10.25:y=340.1:z=1;'
```

Where the values after x,y or z accept values matched by:

```
-?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

How can i reuse that?

Those are the only values that are variables. All others characters must be fixed. I mean, they must be in that exact order.

There is a shorter way to express this?

```
r'^C:x=-?\d{1,3}(.\d{1,2})?:y=-?\d{1,3}(.\d{1,2})?:z=-?\d{1,3}(.\d{1,2})?;$'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Folks do this kind of thing sometimes

```
label_value = r'\w=-?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?'
line = r'^C:{0}:{0}:{0};$'.format( label_value )
line_pat= re.compile( line )
```

This is slightly smarter.

```
label_value = r'(\w)=(-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)'
line = r'^C:{0}:{0}:{0};$'.format( label_value )
line_pat= re.compile( line )
```

Why?  It collects the label and the entire floating-point value, not just the digits to the right of the decimal point.

In the unlikely case that order of labels actually **does** matter.

```
value = r'(-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)'
line = r'^C:x={0}:y={0}:z={0};$'.format( value )
line_pat= re.compile( line )
```

This requires the three labels in the given order.  One of those things that's likely to change.

Comment: I think I'd move the `\w=` out of `label_value` since he said he wanted `x`, `y` and `z` in that exact order. Otherwise, great.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It's a tough call.  When someone says "exactly that order", I hear "typically that order".  I've never seen that kind of thing remain fixed for long.  However, this may be an exception; it's possible that out-of-order is actually a reason to treat the data as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Since the regex I put up had a bug I have removed it.

However whenever I need to develop or test a new regex i generally have a play with online tools that allow you to view the results of your regex in real time.

While not specifically python I generally use this one

- http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

This will return no false negatives, but a small number of false positives:

```
'^C(:[xyz]=-?\d{1,3}(.\d{1,2})?){3}'
```

The false positives are the cases where x, y, and z occur in the wrong combinations (i.e. y:x:z, x:x:z, etc.).